# jquery Autocomplete click event

Tags: php, jquery

```
<div id="display">
    <div align="left" class="display_box">
        <a class="test" href="#">
            <img style="width:25px; float:left; margin-right:6px" src="user_img/gow.jpg">
        </a>
        <input type="hidden" id="uid" value="3">
        <b>b</b>ack&nbsp;<b>b</b>ack<br>
        <span style="font-size:9px; color:#999999">back</span>
    </div>
    <div align="left" class="display_box">
        <a class="test" href="#">
            <img style="width:25px; float:left; margin-right:6px" src="user_img/gow.jpg">
        </a>
        <input type="hidden" id="uid" value="3">
        <b>b</b>ack&nbsp;<b>b</b>ack<br>
        <span style="font-size:9px; color:#999999">back</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am making this auto complete  search function with images in thumbnail like facebook and getting this as html after ajax call .
what i want to do is that if user clicks on any div with class display_box i want to get the value of hidden field in the div...

I tried this code but its not capture click event  how ever if I use #display click event capturing but that is for whole div.

```
$('.display_box').click(function() {
    var id =$(this).find('input[type=hidden]').val();
});
```

Comment: how are you creating these #display blocks? dynamically? also a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would help visualise your code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out the problem actually it was binding the click event with displaybox but there is no existence of display box when program runs initially or until u search so what i did is  i  bind the click event in success of ajax call and now its working ... I hope it helps. actually these divs display_box are dynamically made when user search something coming from database here is the complete code for help to any one

```
              $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
             url: "search.php",
             data: dataString,
             cache: false,
             success: function(html)
           {

            if(html !="")
            {
            $("#display").html(html).show();

    $('.display_box').click(function(){



$('#temp').val($(this).find('input[type=hidden]').val());
    $('#searchbox').val($(this).find('.name').text());
    $('#display').fadeOut('slow');




    });
           }
      }




            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are adding the jQuery file and $ is not conflicted. You can use this line before writing your js code.

```
$ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work.
Check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3JK4c/

Have you put the code inside the document ready function?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    .... code here ....
});
```